# How to get done button action in Movie Player when loading in webView?

Tags: iphone

I am new to Iphone and trying to play video in webView. So, in that i need to have the done button action. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If the video is played in UIWebView then you can access when the video is played and when Done button is pressed using the following code along with the code you have used to load url in webview

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

And it can be accessed through

```
BOOL isVideoInFullScreenMode;//Temperory added here.. must be in .h file or at teh top if required
-(void)videoPlayStarted:(NSNotification *)notification{
//Your stuff here
   isVideoInFullScreenMode = YES;
}

-(void)videoPlayFinished:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //Your stuffs here
    isVideoInFullScreenMode = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution for Done button action...This logic is working for both ipad & iphone  also..
I solved this prob by using UIGestureRecognizer.

Here is my code.

firstly i am adding notification for EnterFullScreen by using

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

Now in youTubeStarted method i added this Code..

```
-(void)youTubeStarted:(NSNotification *)notification{
if (!tapRecognizer1) {
    tapRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    tapRecognizer1.delegate = self;
    [tapRecognizer1 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer1];
}    
}
```

This will add TapRecognizer to the movieplayer..

And now the following delegate method will check that it is done button or not

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
NSLog(@"%@",touch.description);
NSString *ViewName = touch.description ;
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
NSLog(@"location x===%f , location y=== %f",location.x,location.y);
NSRange Check = [ViewName rangeOfString:@"UINavigationButton"];
NSRange checkFrameOfButton;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   checkFrameOfButton = [ViewName rangeOfString:@"frame = (7 7; 50 30)"];
    if (checkFrameOfButton.length <= 0) {
        checkFrameOfButton = [ViewName rangeOfString:@"frame = (7 7; 51 30)"];
    } 
}
else {
    checkFrameOfButton = [ViewName rangeOfString:@"frame = (5 7; 48 30)"];
    if (Check.length<=0) {
        Check = [ViewName rangeOfString:@"UIView"];
    }
}
if (location.y<40 && location.x<85 && Check.length>0 && checkFrameOfButton.length>0) {
    [self endplaying];  
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now in endplaying method you can do what you want...